# Confusion regarding entry date to Canada in the student visa cover letter

Tags: visa, canada

I have a Canadian Student Visa valid from March, 2016 to March, 2018. The letter that I received along with the visa mentions nothing about the date within which I must enter Canada before it expires. In the letter the "**Must enter Canada by**" section is kept blank and in the another part of the letter and in another part of the letter "**You must seek entry to Canada to obtain study permit                    (yyyy/mm/dd/)**" is also left blank. My question is if that is a typographical error or they generally leave it blank in the letter. I am planning to enter Canada in the May, 2017. I have attached segments of the letter with this question. Thanks.[image][image]